# Apply CSS class

Tags: angularjs, css, css-selectors

Using `ng-repeat` directive I have formed 3 rows 2 columns  like tables by using divs then I have 2 CSS classes red and green I want to apply these CSS class the below cases,

1st row 1st column - red class

1st row 2nd column - green class

2nd row 1st column - green class

2nd row 2nd column - red class

3rd row 1st column - red class

3rd row 2nd column - green class

like wise I need to apply the css.

How can I achieve this case?

Comment: Can you show your current code?

Comment: share your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `$even`, `$odd` and `ng-class` to achieve this

```js
var app=angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('ListCtrl',ListCtrl);
function ListCtrl($scope) {
  
  $scope.items = [
    {name: 'foo', value: 'foo value',car:'chevy',model:'vette',year:'2013'},
    {name: 'bar', value: 'bar value'},
    {name: 'baz', value: 'baz value'}
  ];
  
  
}
```

```css
.red{color:red;}
.green{color:green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
          <td ng-class="{'red':$even,'green':$odd}">{{item.name}}</td>
          <td ng-class="{'red':$odd,'green':$even}">{{item.value}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Im using the below code for my project

<div ng-repeat="data in $scope.datas"> 
     <span>{{data.name}}</span> 
</div>

Here how can i use my alternate css class?

Comment: First of all , you cannot use $scope in view. Second just try to understand what is happening in the above code and just do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="data in respdata">                    
    <tr align="left" ng-if="$even">                     
        <td class="red">{{data.id}}</td>
        <td class="green">{{data.first_name}}</td>
        <td>{{data.last_name}}</td>
        <td>{{data.email}}</td>                         
    </tr>
    <tr align="left" ng-if="$odd">                      
        <td class="green">{{data.id}}</td>
        <td class="red">{{data.first_name}}</td>
        <td>{{data.last_name}}</td>
        <td>{{data.email}}</td>                         
    </tr>
</tbody>

<style>
    .green {
         background-color: green;
    }
    .red {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
```

Output like this: 
[image]